# Xunit Namespace Could not be Found in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, xunit

I'm using Visual Studio Code for a .NET Core Project.
I have an ASP.NET Core Project for which i want to create a separate unit tests project, i created a sub folder and ran

```
dotnet new xunit
dotnet restore
```

When i tried to run it from the cli "dotnet build" "dotnet run" it ran successfully, however in visual studio, it says that it can't find the namespace Xunit

[image]
[image]

This is very strange because Visual Studio code has worked fine for me so far, it never had problem with dependencies, it only has this problem with Xunit.

Anyone familiar with this issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I tried opening the test project directly with vscode (instead of opening the root project that contains the test project in a sub folder) and now vscode recognizes Xunit.

I then opened the root project with vscode again, added Xunit to the root project's csproj file, ran "dotnet restore" in the root project and now Xunit is recognized in the test project.

The thing is that vscode (or is it Omnisharp? i'm not sure) probably looks only at the root csproj file and ignores any csproj file that happens to be in a sub folder.

Answer (score 32):

I had the same issue. It was solved by typing "Restart Omnisharp" in the Command Palette.

Comment: It fixes the issue only temporarily.

Comment: after all these years, it's still an issue with restarting OmniSharp ugh

Answer (score 21):

Adding the xunit reference to the root csproj is likely undesirable.

## The Issue

The idea of having tests in a separate csproj is that they and their dependencies won't be included in the main project. Adding xunit to the root csproj will however cause the main project to reference xunit. Depending on how the product is bundled, this will cause the xunit dlls and all the dlls it depends on to be included unnecessarily.

Unfortunately, Omnisharp has an issue with nested csproj. It appears the root csproj will claim all source files in all subdirectories, even if there are nested csproj. This causes the missing reference error.

## The Solution

Do not nest csproj. Note how [Microsoft's xunit setup guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test) puts the main csproj and its tests csproj into different subdirectories of the sln.

I first ran into this error as well and after restructuring the project to not nest csproj, the error was resolved; with only the tests csproj referencing xunit.

Comment: The old csproject file need you to explicit include which folders in the build process. The core one automatically include the folders in the build process unless you exclude them.

Comment: this worked for me, once I had the main and test project directories at the same level under the solution I was able to build successfully. Thanks!

Comment: Yep this worked for me, I was working on an existing project and needed to add integration tests. After creating the Test folder and project, found XUnit not referencing correctly. Moved my sln file to the parent directory, added the test sln, made ref, dotnet restore all good.

Follow the Microsoft xunit setup guide linked by OP.

Answer (score 6):

### Prelude

None of the above worked for me.

Turns out I should have checked my notes from before, as this has been a recurring issue here with a project that uses Xunit:

**Make sure all installed Xunit.xxxxxxxxx packages have the EXACT SAME version.**

The problem occurs while/after having updated my NuGet packages automatically, which will, at the time of writing, install Xunit **2.4.1** (and several other xunit packages at version **2.4.1**) *plus* `xunit.runner.visualstudio` at version **2.4.3** **(!)**

While nothing untoward is reported during this NuGet update, the result is a permanently failing build, where `Fact` and `Assert` are suddenly unknown, e.g.

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Fact' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  Imazen.Test.Webp

### The fix

What did work out for me was to go and **revert** that `xunit.runner.visualstudio` update, re-installing 2.4.1.

BTW, in Visual Studio, this would then look something like this (after the revert/re-install):

[image]

Note that the package manager there is hinting that an update is available and as soon as you apply that 2.4.3 update again, in any way, you're back to square one: a curiously failing build.

The key to the solution is to have **all installed xunit packages with the same version.** -- if only a few have updates available on NuGet, **wait until all xunit packages are available for that same version.**

### Postscript

Don't know ***why*** this is so finicky, as I've only observed this brittle behaviour with `xunit.*`, but this is what has worked earlier this year (I had forgotten) and now had happen to me again, with the same outcome: the mandatory revert of a NuGet xunit package update.

Answer (score 1):

@areller's solution solved my issue. I just want to expand on his answer to provide some sample code, in case there are other people who doesn't know exactly what to do (especially if you just started on C# like I did).

## The Issue

First, I followed instructions here to start writing unit tests for a .NET Core application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test

Then I encountered the same issue mentioned by OP.

## Solution

First, I tried Claus' solution by restarting OmniSharp, but it doesn't fix the issue.

Then, following @areller's suggestion, I found these lines in `Tests.csproj`:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.3.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I copied that, and pasted in my root directory's `.csproj` file, so the root `.csproj` looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.3.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

After that, VS Code asks me to restore. The VS Code dialog came with a "Restore" button; I clicked on that; several seconds later the issue is gone.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes but no, why? Read @Adrian's answer... this is the issue: "added Xunit to the root project's csproj file" - we don't want xunit reference in the root csproj that's the whole thing...

Comment: 2021 and I'm still having this same issue while adding unit tests to a dotnet core 5 project through CLI... is it really not fixed yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I installed xunit.extensibility.core (2.4.1) for my .Net 5 solution and it solved the issue. xunit.runner.visualstudio (2.4.3) was already present.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, but in my case it was simply because `xunit` was not installed.

```
dotnet add package xunit
```